# Authentication errors when sending intermittent emails from gmail using Heroku / node.js / emailjs

Tags: node.js, email, session, authentication, heroku

I am running a scraper app on Heroku that sends emails every once in a while. Sometimes it'll be every 2 minutes, sometimes it won't send anything for 2 days-depends on what the scraper finds. I am running into continual errors with email authentication. I have tried configuring the email with nodemailer and emailjs. Both run into the same issue. I am wondering if it is because of the way Heroku servers are distributed?

I have taken the following steps:

1) unlocked the account at: https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

2) allowed less secure apps here: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

With both nodemailer and emailjs, I notice that it works fine for a couple hours but then if no emails are sent for a day, as soon as it tries to send another one I receive an authentication error. Here is the code using emailjs that works for a couple hours then fails with an authentication error:

```
var server  = email.server.connect({
       user:    process.env.CRAWLER_MAIL, 
       password:process.env.CRAWLER_PWD, 
       host:    "smtp.gmail.com", 
       ssl:     true
    });

    var message = {
    text:   "Placeholder", 
    from:   'NAME <'+ process.env.CRAWLER_MAIL+'>', 
    to:     eachEmail[0],
    subject:    emailSubject,
    attachment: 
    [
      {data:emailBody, alternative:true}
    ]
    };

    server.send(message, function(err, message) { console.log(err || message); });
```

And here is the error from the Heroku log:

```
 Error: authorization.failed (bad response on command '[redacted]': -5.7.14 https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=[redacted]-)
```

I don't use 2-step verification for this account, so I don't think I need an app password. Any other ideas about how I can get this to consistently work?

Comment: seems like a _session_ issue, getting expired after some time

Comment: Thanks @wrangler I have updated the tags so maybe someone who knows about sessions will chime in.